# How to make table update my otp code in database properly?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on adding otp verification in my app. Problem is When i click register my app or rest api will generate new code but when use is exist app won't generate it again and nothing gonna update in my database. I'm not really experienced in this section, but this is what I've developed, as u can see there is a Update stmt in code which I've added when it was working without update, but after all this also didn't worked.

Here are the things happen for creating user :

Register=>If is not exist Create otp and add phone and otp to database => complete form => go to app.

Register=>If it's exist check phone, update otp => go to app

Here are the codes :

Function :

```
function checkExistsUser($phone)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Phone=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    }else{
        $stmt->close();
        return false;
    }
}
public function verifyOtp($otp)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT otp FROM User WHERE otp= ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$otp);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    }else{
        $stmt->close();
        return false;
    }

    public function registerNewOtp($phone,$otp)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO User(Phone,otp) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $phone,$otp);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Phone = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $phone);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE User SET otp WHERE Phone = ?");
            $stmt2->bind_param("i", $updateotp);
            $result = $stmt2->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
        } else
            return false;
    }
```

register.php

```
$response = array();
if(isset($_POST['phone']))
{
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $otp = rand(100000, 999999);

    if($db->checkExistsUser($phone))
{

    $db->updateOtp($phone, $otp);
    echo json_encode($response);
    $response["otp_created"] = "User already existed with " . $phone . " New Code IS $otp";
    sendSms($phone, $otp);



}
    else
    {
        //Create new User
        $user = $db->registerNewOtp($phone,$otp);
        if($user)
        {
            $response['phone'] = $user["Phone"];
            echo json_encode($response);
            // send sms
            sendSms($phone, $otp);
        }
        else
        {
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unkown  error Occuired in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}
else{
    $response["error_msg"]= "Required parameter (phone) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

UpdateOtp function :

```
public function updateOtp($phone, $otp)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE `User` SET `otp` = ? WHERE Phone = ?") or die($this->conn->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $phone,$otp);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    return $result;
}
```

Now i'm getting [] in response.

My changes :

```
Functions :

public function getOtpRecord($phone)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT otp FROM User WHERE Phone=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else
        return NULL;
}


public function updateOtp($phone)
{
    $otp = rand(100000, 999999);
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE `User` SET `otp` = $otp WHERE Phone = ?") or die($this->conn->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $phone);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    return $result;
}

In register :

if($db->checkExistsUser($phone))
{
    if ($db->updateOtp($phone))
    {

        $user = $db->getOtpRecord($phone);

        if($user)
        {
            $otp = $user["otp"];

            echo json_encode($response);
            sendSms($phone, $otp);

        }
        else
        {
            $response["error_msg"] = "User does not exists!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        $response["otp_created"] = "User already existed with " .$phone . " New Code IS $otp";
    }

}
```

With my changes, database gonna update and sms will send with correct otp, but i'm getting [] Response.

Comment: you are checking for the existence of the user, within this condition scope you are not registering any new records in the database ! you are only sending the SMS

Comment: @hassan well i'm not really experienced at this part, can u tell me what should i add or how to fix my mistake? i've tried to create another function to update otp and call it in checkuserexist to update it but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update stuff is in the wrong place.

```
if($db->checkExistsUser($phone))
{
    $db->updateOtp($phone, $otp)
    // etc
}
else
{
    //Create new User
    $user = $db->registerNewOtp($phone,$otp);
    // etc
}
```

Create an update method and move your update code. Also, the update statement isn't actually updating anything! Change it to:

```
"UPDATE User SET otp = ? WHERE Phone = ?"
```

i.e. you need to bind the otp value!

Comment: thanks for response. i've updated my question, i've done what u've said. now i'm getting [] in rest api and still database is not changing.

Comment: check my own changes. i've could update it and get sms but i'm getting [] in reponse.

Comment: you say `echo json_encode($response);` But $response is declared earlier on as an empty array

Comment: Jeasus, i've fixed that part with `$response["otp"] = $user["otp"];` and i've got success echo, now how to use that `$user["otp"]` in `sendSms($phone, $user)` ?

Comment: that's a separate question ;-) Can you mark my answer as correct please? As for the next bit, just get your sendSms method to accept 3 arguments, but default the third argument to null. `function sendSms($user, $phone, $otp = null)`

Comment: sure, mate. thanks for response, you can update your answer base on my last edit, because my changes worked, somehow your answer is also right but i don't know why won't work just like all with my code, i've tried this before with other method. nvm. thanks